# Is there an adapter to use a regular phone with Skype or Google Voice?

Tags: skype, voip, google-voice

Is there an adapter to use a regular phone with Skype or Google Voice?
I found this [Dlink adapter](http://www.dlink.ca/products/default.aspx?pid=466) but it is discontinued, any idea why? Will it still work in Canada and in the US? Any suggestions for other adapters?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Google Voice requires a separate phone number (mobile or landline) to work. You may be thinking about Google Chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linksys SP2102](http://www.orcacom.co.nz/_product_36761/Linksys_SPA2102_-_ATA) is the one my company provides for itsVoIP customers, but basically any analog to digital device will suffice. Should work in US and Canada fine, but I don't know how well any given adapter would work with skype.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we use another VoIP company, but to convert «old» phones to IP, we use Linksys PAP2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_PAP2

I dont know if they're available in your country, but give it a try.